# Diffeomorphisms, derivative and vector space isomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry

My question is about the Corollary 8.6 of Loring's *An Introduction to Manifolds*. Namely,

> If $F:N\to M$ is a diffeomorphism of manifolds and $p \in N$, then $F_*:T_pN\to T_{F(p)}M$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces.

The given proof is as simple as

> $(G\circ F)_* = G_* \circ F_* = (1_N)_* = 1_{T_pN}$, and $(F\circ G)_* = F_* \circ G_* = (1_M)_* = 1_{T_{F(p)}M}$ for the differentiable inverse $G:M \to N$ of $F$. Hence $F_*$ and $G_*$ are vector space isomorphisms.

What I don't understand is that how this shows that $F_*$ and $G_*$ are vector space isomorphisms? Sure, the composition of any function with its inverse is the identity mapping, whose derivative in turn is yet again an identity map. But how does this prove the isomorphism of the individual derivatives?

Comment: A vector space isomorphism is by definition an invertible morphism of vector spaces. Here you show that $F_*$ is invertible by giving the inverse.

Comment: What's your definition of vector space isomorphism?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos A linear and bijective mapping between vector spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G_*\circ F_*=\operatorname{Id}_{T_pN}$, $F_*$ is injective. And, since $F_*\circ G_*=\operatorname{Id}_{T_{f(p)}M}$, $F_*$ is surjective. Besides, $F_*$ is linear. So, $F_*$ is a vector space isomorphism.

Comment: Ah, I see. 99.99% of the time I proof bijectivity with the usual *"consider elements, $x, y$ etc.*, but in this case this is handled by the mere fact that $F_*$ and $G_*$ have inverses!

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.